# Connecting php docker to mqtt docker

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am developing an application in IBM Bluemix. I am having two dockers

1. Mqtt broker docker (https://github.com/mezz64/mqtt-broker-docker-image)
2. Php apache based docker(https://github.com/tutumcloud/apache-php)

I am having a python code on my machine through which I intend to publish a message to Mqtt broker. Once published, I want the php docker to subscribe to Mqtt broker docker and display the message.

I am trying to connect to mqtt broker from php docker by giving the address of mqtt docker in php code as follows:

```
$mqtt = new phpMQTT("169.44.113.133",1883, "PHPMQTTTrial"); //Change client name to something unique

if(!$mqtt->connect()){
echo "failed";
    exit(1);
}
else
{
 echo "Success";
}

$topics['ferries/IOW/#'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"procmsg");
$mqtt->subscribe($topics,0);

while($mqtt->proc()){

echo "hi";

}


$mqtt->close();

function procmsg($topic,$msg){
        echo "Msg Recieved: ".date("r")."\nTopic:{$topic}\n$msg\n";
}
```

However, it fails to connect. 
Can someone guide and tell me how to go about this?

Comment: What's the error message?
How did you start the containers (provide the command)?
My guess is, that you have to link the PHP container to the MQTT container.

Comment: Where does 169.44.113.133 come from? Why not the container name?

Comment: @Martin It is showing blank page for the php ip.

Comment: @mustaccio ip is the address of the mosquitto docker container. I tried replacing that with the name of mosquitto docker container, yet it is showing the blank page.

Comment: 169.44.113.133 is a globally routed IP address - are you sure that is the IP of the container? Where did you get this information?

Comment: @Martin I had added that as example. I am using the container IP only. But it is not working. I tried linking the containers too.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to create a network and both containers should run on the
   same network using `--network`.
2. Instead of the IP and the port, just use `mqtt` in the code to
   connect to the `mqtt` container.

Make sure to name the container when you run it by adding `--name mqtt` and docker will do the mapping for you